# conflicting beans while autowiring even though the bean type is enforced

Tags: java, spring

I have two beans of the classes - `com.abc.MyClass` and `com.xyz.MyClass`

And I am using both of them in different classes -

```
@Component
public class Class1{
  @Autowired
  private com.abc.MyClass myClass;
  ...
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class Class2{
  @Autowired
  private com.xyz.MyClass myClass;
  ...
}
```

It gives ConflictingBeanDefinitionException because bean names are same "myClass", which is expected. My doubt is, what can I do to resolve this to inject beans by type. 
I tried using `Resource` and enforced the type -

```
@Resource(type=com.xyz.MyClass)
private com.xyz.MyClass myClass;
```

But this did not work either. Still gives `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException`

Comment: Did you use annotation or xml?

Comment: I'm using annotations.

Answer (score 0):

you can use @Qualifier("beanName") annotation to resolve conflict by specfying exact bean name you want to map

Answer (score 0):

The rule of the thumb is never rely on auto-generated names. By default bean name would be de-capitalized non-qualified class name. In your case

```
class 1 -> com.abc.MyClass
class 2 -> com.xyz.MyClass
```

Non-qualified class names are the same(MyClass) so in spring context there would be

```
class 1 -> myClass
class 2 -> myClass
```

Above won't happen as those values have to be unique therefore you getting `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException`

As pointed out `@Component("name")` is the sollution to your problem.
If you want to check auto-generated name your bean may implement `BeanNameAware` interface which is container callback which pass bean name to your bean.